# Should prepared statement ever be used without placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Obviously no threat of SQL injection, but are there any performance considerations of using a prepared statement instead of a `query()` if there are no variables inserted into the prepared statement?

```
$sql='SELECT t1.a,t1.b,t2.c FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1.t2_id';
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
while(true) {
  ...
  //Should this be used
  $stmt->execute();
  //or this, and get rid of the above prepared statement?
  $rs=$db->query($sql);

  $rs=$stmt->fetchAll();
  ...
}
```

EDIT.  lonesomeday's and Your Common Sense's answers are conflicting, yet both correct as I failed to state whether I am am using emulation mode.  I don't, however, feel it is appropriate for me to fundamentally edit the original question at this point, and wish I could select both...

Comment: You said you are using `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` so you are NOT using emulation mode.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  I recognize I am NOT using emulation mode, but I failed to say so in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

In this precise case, yes, because you are looping.

By using prepared statements, you are sending the query to MySQL just the once, and it is only parsed once. If you just send the SQL each time, it has to re-parse it rather than re-using the same code.

In the loop, you are re-executing the query multiple times, so it is (microscopically) more efficient to use the same SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *should*, but just out of common sense it would be a reasonable idea ut use `query()` method for a query that doesn't contain placeholders.

However, the above makes any sense if you are using PDO with [emulation mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) turned off. Otherwise the prepare/execute pair will be in effect just like a single query() call.

However, given that it is recommended to turn emulation mode off, I would implement a simple PDO wrapper this way

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        if (!$args) return $this->query($sql);
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Obviously, there is a case mentioned in the other answer, but I hardly can imagine a case where it could be used.

Comment: My typical PDO config uses `[
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES          => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY  => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                   => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE        => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ]`

Comment: So query() instead of prepare will save you a roundtrip to database in such a case. The difference is considered negligible, but well, just for sake of it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In all fairness, I can't imagine using it either. It just seemed like what was being asked in the question.

Comment: @lonesomeday if you blindly trust to an opening poster, you'll learn that in the Lake Erie there are dragons. And mermaids. Still I see not a slightest sense in the code posted. Do you? Besides, although you guys prefer to be servile towards certain OP, my aim is much more general audience and thus more generalized answers.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Have a lovely day.